# How do I check the expiration date on a memcached entry

Tags: memcached

I'm running apache/php/memcached on ubuntu 12.04

The keys I am setting are persisting beyond their expiration.  We are using the same code that worked with the memcached PAAS we are migrating from.

How do I confirm that the expiration is actually being set on a key?

If I telnet and get [mykey] it simply shows the value, not the expiration.

Comment: no answers yet?

Answer (score 0):

You can verify the expiration time of an item in memcached by running `stats cachedump` command. Cachedump require two numeric arguments; item index, and the number of items to display. Memcached will return a list of items with size (in bytes), and a unix timestamp.

Example telnet session

```
// Add something to cache
>> set apples 0 130 3
>> Foo
<< STORED

// List ITEM stats
>> stats items
<< STAT items:1:number 1
<< STAT items:1:age 7
<< STAT items:1:evicted 0
<< STAT items:1:evicted_nonzero 0
<< STAT items:1:evicted_time 0
<< STAT items:1:outofmemory 0
<< STAT items:1:tailrepairs 0
<< STAT items:1:reclaimed 0
<< STAT items:1:expired_unfetched 0
<< STAT items:1:evicted_unfetched 0
<< END

// Verify expiration time
>> stats cachedump 1 1
<< ITEM apples [3 b; 1393944062 s]
<< END
```

And 1393944062 => Tue, 04 Mar 2014 08:41:02 -0600